# Launching windows phone 8 app from webpage

Tags: windows-phone-8

I added a uri association to my WMAppManifest.xml file in my Windows Phone 8 project and I'm able to successfully launch my app from within another app using `LaunchUriAsync`. I've also registered the same protocol in my Windows 8 project.

```
// windows phone 8 uri map
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="myprotocol" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

On Windows 8, I am able to launch the app with by a simple hyperlink using my given protocol *"myprotocol:"*.

On Windows Phone 8, I tried typing the protocol in the browser location bar, but I get an IE error saying this type of address is not supported. This makes me concerned I won't be able to launch my app from a web page simply by using my app specific protocol in the hyperlink.

Does anybody have any experience with this? Am I just paranoid?

fyi: here's the info on [URI Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_URIassociations) in WP8

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the simple answer is often overlooked.

Yes, everything is in place to function correctly. It appears to only be a restriction with IE Mobile.

I set up a web page on my server with a link click me and was able to successfully launch my app view IE Mobile on the emulator.